# How to read a large .csv file as table with bookstyle?

Tags: tables, booktabs, csv, csvsimple, large-files

I need to insert large tables in the appendix of my MSc thesis and I want to read the data from `.csv` files without fill the `.tex` file where I write.
I produce the tables with the help of [TableGenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/). Let us consider the following cutted `.csv` file:

```
    1,    459872    ,      2459600.5,    0.245955429393969E+07,    0.150902180397680E+09,    0.700936137135535E-01,    0.444423490130398E+02,    0.509894719093894E+02,    0.449518800380460E+02,    0.972856801473429E+00
    2,    1991 VG   ,      2459600.5,    0.245965301734296E+07,    0.154448562453878E+09,    0.524440272062934E-01,    0.981969077945011E+02,    0.305901193619353E+03,    0.310657729272394E+03,    0.939542405344313E+00
    3,    2000 SG344,      2459600.5,    0.245967142235446E+07,    0.146215475380197E+09,    0.668906906224866E-01,    0.107259306095888E+03,    0.280186369328737E+03,    0.287658863754547E+03,    0.102000471918105E+01
    4,    2003 YN107,      2459600.5,    0.245973765703815E+07,    0.147913409318582E+09,    0.138963447919681E-01,    0.352070216744272E+03,    0.221439015133514E+03,    0.222501180674322E+03,    0.100249189670507E+01
    5,    2006 JY26 ,      2459600.5,    0.245950771201134E+07,    0.151137260433216E+09,    0.831296262363333E-01,    0.317110762865456E+03,    0.995403784006208E+02,    0.900588991605521E+02,    0.970587901094867E+00
    6,    2006 QQ56 ,      2459600.5,    0.245948919576395E+07,    0.147356242165350E+09,    0.455957054639189E-01,    0.132721216278857E+03,    0.116944610798197E+03,    0.112215042556733E+03,    0.100818303543359E+01
```

My code to produce the table with help of above website is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{
c
l
c
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation = true]
}
\toprule
\textbf{index} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{pdes}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}epoch \\ (JDTDB)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}tp\\ (JDTDB)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{a\_km}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{e}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{w\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ta\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ma\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{n\_deg/d}} \\ \midrule
1 & 459872 & 2459600.5 & 0.245955429393969E+07 & 0.150902180397680E+09 & 0.700936137135535E-01 & 0.444423490130398E+02 & 0.509894719093894E+02 & 0.449518800380460E+02 & 0.972856801473429E+00 \\
2 & 1991 VG & 2459600.5 & 0.245965301734296E+07 & 0.154448562453878E+09 & 0.524440272062934E-01 & 0.981969077945011E+02 & 0.305901193619353E+03 & 0.310657729272394E+03 & 0.939542405344313E+00 \\
3 & 2000 SG344 & 2459600.5 & 0.245967142235446E+07 & 0.146215475380197E+09 & 0.668906906224866E-01 & 0.107259306095888E+03 & 0.280186369328737E+03 & 0.287658863754547E+03 & 0.102000471918105E+01 \\
4 & 2003 YN107 & 2459600.5 & 0.245973765703815E+07 & 0.147913409318582E+09 & 0.138963447919681E-01 & 0.352070216744272E+03 & 0.221439015133514E+03 & 0.222501180674322E+03 & 0.100249189670507E+01 \\
5 & 2006 JY26 & 2459600.5 & 0.245950771201134E+07 & 0.151137260433216E+09 & 0.831296262363333E-01 & 0.317110762865456E+03 & 0.995403784006208E+02 & 0.900588991605521E+02 & 0.970587901094867E+00 \\
6 & 2006 QQ56 & 2459600.5 & 0.245948919576395E+07 & 0.147356242165350E+09 & 0.455957054639189E-01 & 0.132721216278857E+03 & 0.116944610798197E+03 & 0.112215042556733E+03 & 0.100818303543359E+01 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output_table]

I read some questions talking about the `csvsimple` package, can you help me read the `.csv` file to create the professional table with the booktab style without entering the data in the `.tex` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you table is going to be also large vertically, and possibly span multiple pages, you probably want to apply one of the long tables: `longtable`, `xltabular` etc.

Below is an example of using `csvsimple` and `xltabular`. I applied `landscape` as the table is quite wide with `\newgeometry` to slightly increase margins on pages occupied by the table. I also added solutions form `makecell` to simplify code when dealing with multiple lines

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=figures,
    round-precision=3,
}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{c}

\begin{document}
Some text here

\newgeometry{margin=3cm,a4paper}   % Starts new page
\begin{landscape}
    % \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{xltabular}{0.93\linewidth}{
            @{} c X
            S[table-format=7.1, round-mode=none]
            *7{S[table-format=1.3e1]}
            @{}
        }
        \caption{The table\label{tab:label}}\\[-6pt]
        \toprule
        {\thead{idx.}}
        & {\thead[l]{pdes}}
        & {\thead{epoch\\(JDTDB)}}
        & {\thead{tp\\(JDTDB)}}
        & {\thead{a\_km}}
        & {\thead{e}}
        & {\thead{w\_deg}}
        & {\thead{ta\_deg}}
        & {\thead{ma\_def}}
        & {\thead{n\_deg/d}} \\
        \midrule \endhead
        \bottomrule \endfoot
        \csvreader[
            no head,
            late after line = \\,
        ]{sample.csv}{}%
        {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii
        & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii
        & \csvcolix & \csvcolx
    }
    \end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry   % Adds pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT. ~Code generating vertical table~

Edit 2.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}

\sisetup{
  round-mode=figures,
  round-precision = 3,
  exponent-product = {\hspace{-1pt}\times\hspace{-2pt}},
}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top, skip=3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{c}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \small
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{The table}
  \label{tab:label}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
        @{} c l
        S[table-format=7.1, round-mode=none]
        *3{S[table-format=1.3e1]}
        @{\hspace{12pt}}
        S[table-format=1.3e1]
        @{}
    }
    \toprule
    {\thead{idx.}}
    & {\thead[l]{pdes}}
    & {\thead{epoch\\(JDTDB)}}
    & {\thead{a\_km}}
    & {\thead{e}}
    & {\thead{w\_deg}}
    & {\thead{ta\_deg}} \\
    \midrule
    \csvreader[
      no head,
      late after line = \\,
    ]{sample.csv}{}{%
      \csvcoli  & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv
      & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii
    }
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I plan to delete some columns, can you show how to produce the table vertically, i.e. without the use of landscape?

Comment: I have made a few changes and post a new code. The easiest way to render a vertical table is to substitute `table` with `sidewaystable`. In case you have _twoside_ document, have a look at page 2 of [rotating](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) documentation in case you need to change orientation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Celdor. Yeas, I use `twoside` document. Howvere I decided to not display the columns 4,9 and 10. Can you kindly update the code? I guess I have to remove `\csvcol` ...

Comment: Yes, you need to change number of elements generated from csv, as so a number of columns in two other places: headings and a column definition. Because you removed three columns, the table can now fit the page using regular `table`. I hope this is sorted now.

Comment: Can you kindly modify your answer in order to create the table without the above mentioned columns?

Comment: The code is already updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140379/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-celdor).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not to scale the table but instead use a smaller font and decrease the column sep length. Other than that, assuming your data sits in a file named `data.csv`, the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}

\newcolumntype{Z}{S[table-format=-1.3e1, round-precision=3, scientific-notation=true]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}{%
\scriptsize%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
\begin{tabular}{clc*{7}{Z}}
\toprule
\textbf{index} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{pdes}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}epoch \\ (JDTDB)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}tp\\ (JDTDB)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{a\_km}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{e}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{w\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ta\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ma\_deg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{n\_deg/d}} \\ \midrule
\csvreader[
    no head,
    late after line = \\
]{data.csv}{}{%
    \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix & \csvcolx
}%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]