# Issue with rules when display csv file in a tabular

Tags: tables, csv

I'm trying to display values from a csv file inside a tabular. To do so, I'm using the macro `\csvreader`. I would like thr tabulat to like this way :

[image: desired result]

with a `toprule`, the head of columns, a `midrule`, the values with no line and a `bottomrule`.

Here is the code I made

```
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}%
    \toprule
    \textbf{Mesh} & $h$ & \textbf{nDof $\P_1$} & \textbf{nDof $\P_2$}\\
    \midrule
    \csvreader[head to column names]{fig/meshInformation3D.csv}{}
    {\texttt{\mesh} & \pgfmathprintnumber{\hAvg} & \pgfmathprintnumber{\nDofPUn} & \pgfmathprintnumber{\nDofPDeux}\\}
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

For each line, I display the information of the csv row, then I insert a `\\`. With this code, I get the following result

[image: result]

with an additional empty line. I tried to remove the `\\` in front of the `\bottomrule`, but it result in the error `Misclaced \noalign. \bottomrule->\noalign`.

How could I remove this extra line ?

Comment: You should probably use the option `late after line = \\ `. See the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664128/47927). Did you take a look at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.pdf)? The manual has a lot of nice examples, including the use of `\bottomrule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the option `late after line=\\` solves this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{mylist.csv}
mesh, hAvg, nDofPUn, nDofPDeux 
M0  , 0.86, 47384  , 327000    
M1  , 0.74, 68993  , 473000    
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}%
    \toprule
    \textbf{Mesh} & $h$ & \textbf{nDof $\mathbb{P}_1$} & \textbf{nDof $\mathbb{P}_2$} \\
    \midrule
    \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\]{mylist.csv}{}{
        \texttt{\mesh} & 
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\hAvg} & 
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\nDofPUn} & 
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\nDofPDeux}
    }
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]